# ZIpArchive not found

Tags: phpexcel

Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in /home/coaster/public_html/system/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php on line 234.
I am using the version of extension 2.31 in opencart.

How to solve this?

Comment: Version 2.31 of what? There is no version 2.31 of PHPExcel; the latest version is 1.8.1

Comment: Google the error message, e.g. `Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found opencart`

Answer (score 2):

The [ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class is available in the [ZIP extension](https://pecl.php.net/package/zip). You want to [install](https://www.google.pl/search?q=linux%20how%20install%20zip%20extension) the zip extension first. You can do that with handy app called `pecl` which installs PHP extensions: `pecl install zip`.

If you don't have the `pecl` app installed, you can do that with your favorite package manager, for instance: `apt-get install pecl`.

To check if the extension was installed successfuly, you can check via command line

```
php -r "echo extension_loaded('zip') ? 'Installed' : 'Not installed';"
```

or

```
php -m | grep zip
```

Comment: How can i do this in c-panel?

Answer (score 1):

In the console run:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip
```

and be sure to restart apache after that.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done self as well if you have cPanel access:

**STEP 1**:

Go to Cpanel - PHP Pear Packages - Find PHP Extension - Search for zip.
Install the zip extension found.

**STEP 2:**

Go to Cpanel - Select PHP Version - Tick the zip Option - Save.

Now try to upload the .ocmod.zip file. Should work now.
Worked for me.